# Why is ligature glyph 'fl' missing when matplotlib exports to svg?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I have found a problem when i want to export a matplotlib plot to svg file. If a label/title contains a ligature glyph (such as fl in flow), it is not exported to the svg file. If I save to pdf, than it is ok.

Here is a screenshot from matplotlib:
[image: Screenshot from matplotlib - it contains the full hading and label]

Here is the svg file (converted to png by CorelDraw):
fl is missing in the heading and in the y-label.
[image: svg file - converted to png by CorelDraw]

Here is a working python code to reproduce the plots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

from matplotlib import rc
rc("pdf", fonttype=3)
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Mass flow rate [kg/s]')
plt.title("Example with flow")

plt.savefig('tex_demo.pdf', format='pdf')
plt.savefig('tex_demo.svg', format='svg')
plt.show()
```

When I run the script, I get a bunch of warning messages, which also occur in case I do not have the fl-glyph in the labels:

```
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.6.5.0Qt5\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py:389: UserWarning: The glyph (48) of font (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb) cannot be converted with the encoding. Glyph may be wrong
"be wrong" % (glyph, font_bunch.filename))
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.6.5.0Qt5\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py:389: UserWarning: The glyph (50) of font (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb) cannot be converted with the encoding. Glyph may be wrong
"be wrong" % (glyph, font_bunch.filename))
```

What could be the reason?

Addition: The problem is somehow related to the usage of the font Times (which is for my case mandatory, the usage of usetex=True is also mandatory as I need need to plot formulas in my full problem). If I switch to standard TeX font, than no problem occurs:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc("pdf", fonttype=3)
rc('font',**{'family':'serif'})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

For me, a sufficient solution would be, if fl is exported by two separate glyphs f and l.

As requested I have added the svg file (in reduced form because of 30000 chars stackoverflow limits). All characters are transferred to curves in the file. Search for "flow rate" to find the corrosponding section in the snippet.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Created with matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/) -->
<svg height="345.6pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 460.8 345.6" width="460.8pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
*{stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;}
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="figure_1">
  <g id="patch_1">
   <path d="M 0 345.6 
L 460.8 345.6 
L 460.8 0 
L 0 0 
z
" style="fill:#ffffff;"/>
  </g>
  <g id="axes_1">
   <g id="patch_2">
    <path d="M 57.6 307.584 
L 414.72 307.584 
L 414.72 41.472 
L 57.6 41.472 
z
" style="fill:#ffffff;"/>
   </g>
   <g id="matplotlib.axis_1">
    <g id="xtick_1">
     <g id="line2d_1">
      <defs>
       <path d="M 0 0 
L 0 3.5 
" id="ma1151f6d85" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;"/>
      </defs>
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="57.6" xlink:href="#ma1151f6d85" y="307.584"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_1">
      <!-- $0.0$ -->
      <defs>
       <path d="M 25.40625 68 
C 19.90625 68 15.703125 66.3125 12 62.8125 
C 6.203125 57.203125 2.40625 45.703125 2.40625 34 
C 2.40625 23.109375 5.703125 11.40625 10.40625 5.8125 
C 14.09375 1.40625 19.203125 -1 25 -1 
C 30.09375 -1 34.40625 0.703125 38 4.203125 
C 43.796875 9.703125 47.59375 21.3125 47.59375 33.40625 
C 47.59375 53.90625 38.5 68 25.40625 68 
z
M 25.09375 65.40625 
C 33.5 65.40625 38 54.109375 38 33.203125 
C 38 12.3125 33.59375 1.609375 25 1.609375 
C 16.40625 1.609375 12 12.3125 12 33.109375 
C 12 54.3125 16.5 65.40625 25.09375 65.40625 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <path d="M 19.203125 5.28125 
C 19.203125 8.15625 16.796875 10.546875 13.90625 10.546875 
C 11 10.546875 8.59375 8.15625 8.59375 5.28125 
C 8.59375 2.390625 11 0 13.90625 0 
C 16.796875 0 19.203125 2.390625 19.203125 5.28125 
z
" id="CMMI10-58"/>
      </defs>
      <g transform="translate(51.238905 321.338578)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="xtick_2">
     <g id="line2d_2">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="129.024" xlink:href="#ma1151f6d85" y="307.584"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_2">
      <!-- $0.2$ -->
      <defs>
       <path d="M 47.5 13.671875 
L 46.203125 14.171875 
C 42.5 8.5 41.203125 7.59375 36.703125 7.59375 
L 12.796875 7.59375 
L 29.59375 25.140625 
C 38.5 34.40625 42.40625 41.984375 42.40625 49.765625 
C 42.40625 59.734375 34.296875 67.390625 23.90625 67.390625 
C 18.40625 67.390625 13.203125 65.203125 9.5 61.21875 
C 6.296875 57.8125 4.796875 54.625 3.09375 47.546875 
L 5.203125 47.046875 
C 9.203125 56.8125 12.796875 60 19.703125 60 
C 28.09375 60 33.796875 54.3125 33.796875 45.9375 
C 33.796875 38.171875 29.203125 28.90625 20.796875 20.03125 
L 3 1.203125 
L 3 0 
L 42 0 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-50"/>
      </defs>
      <g transform="translate(122.662905 321.338578)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-50"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="xtick_3">
     <g id="line2d_3">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="200.448" xlink:href="#ma1151f6d85" y="307.584"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_3">
      <!-- $0.4$ -->
      <defs>
       <path d="M 47.203125 23.390625 
L 37 23.390625 
L 37 68 
L 32.59375 68 
L 1.203125 23.390625 
L 1.203125 17 
L 29.296875 17 
L 29.296875 0.5 
L 37 0.5 
L 37 17 
L 47.203125 17 
z
M 29.203125 23.390625 
L 5.203125 23.390625 
L 29.203125 57.78125 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-52"/>
      </defs>
      <g transform="translate(194.086905 321.338578)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-52"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="xtick_4">
     <g id="line2d_4">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="271.872" xlink:href="#ma1151f6d85" y="307.584"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_4">
      <!-- $0.6$ -->
      <defs>
       <path d="M 44.59375 68.609375 
C 33.203125 67.609375 27.40625 65.703125 20.09375 60.609375 
C 9.296875 52.90625 3.40625 41.5 3.40625 28.15625 
C 3.40625 19.5 6.09375 10.75 10.40625 5.78125 
C 14.203125 1.390625 19.59375 -1 25.796875 -1 
C 38.203125 -1 46.796875 8.453125 46.796875 22.203125 
C 46.796875 34.9375 39.5 43 28 43 
C 23.59375 43 21.5 42.296875 15.203125 38.5 
C 17.90625 53.609375 29.09375 64.40625 44.796875 67 
z
M 24.203125 38.40625 
C 32.796875 38.40625 37.796875 31.25 37.796875 18.8125 
C 37.796875 7.875 33.90625 1.8125 26.90625 1.8125 
C 18.09375 1.8125 12.703125 11.15625 12.703125 26.5625 
C 12.703125 31.640625 13.5 34.421875 15.5 35.921875 
C 17.59375 37.5 20.703125 38.40625 24.203125 38.40625 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-54"/>
      </defs>
      <g transform="translate(265.510905 321.338578)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-54"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="xtick_5">
     <g id="line2d_5">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="343.296" xlink:href="#ma1151f6d85" y="307.584"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_5">
      <!-- $0.8$ -->
      <defs>
       <path d="M 29 37.5 
C 38.90625 42.8125 42.40625 47 42.40625 53.8125 
C 42.40625 62 35.203125 68 25.203125 68 
C 14.296875 68 6.203125 61.3125 6.203125 52.203125 
C 6.203125 45.703125 8.09375 42.8125 18.59375 33.609375 
C 7.796875 25.40625 5.59375 22.3125 5.59375 15.5 
C 5.59375 5.8125 13.5 -1 24.796875 -1 
C 36.796875 -1 44.5 5.609375 44.5 15.90625 
C 44.5 23.609375 41.09375 28.5 29 37.5 
z
M 27.203125 27.203125 
C 34.5 22 36.90625 18.40625 36.90625 12.8125 
C 36.90625 6.3125 32.40625 1.8125 25.90625 1.8125 
C 18.296875 1.8125 13.203125 7.609375 13.203125 16.3125 
C 13.203125 22.703125 15.40625 26.90625 21.203125 31.609375 
z
M 26.09375 39.3125 
C 17.203125 45.109375 13.59375 49.703125 13.59375 55.3125 
C 13.59375 61.109375 18.09375 65.203125 24.40625 65.203125 
C 31.203125 65.203125 35.5 60.8125 35.5 53.90625 
C 35.5 48.203125 32.703125 43.703125 27 39.90625 
C 26.5 39.609375 26.5 39.609375 26.09375 39.3125 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-56"/>
      </defs>
      <g transform="translate(336.934905 321.338578)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-56"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="xtick_6">
     <g id="line2d_6">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="414.72" xlink:href="#ma1151f6d85" y="307.584"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_6">
      <!-- $1.0$ -->
      <defs>
       <path d="M 29.09375 67.796875 
L 11.09375 58.703125 
L 11.09375 57.296875 
C 12.296875 57.796875 13.40625 58.203125 13.796875 58.40625 
C 15.59375 59.109375 17.296875 59.5 18.296875 59.5 
C 20.40625 59.5 21.296875 57.984375 21.296875 54.765625 
L 21.296875 9.25 
C 21.296875 5.921875 20.5 3.625 18.90625 2.703125 
C 17.40625 1.8125 16 1.5 11.796875 1.5 
L 11.796875 0 
L 39.40625 0 
L 39.40625 1.5 
C 31.5 1.5 29.90625 2.5 29.90625 7.34375 
L 29.90625 67.609375 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-49"/>
      </defs>
      <g transform="translate(408.358905 321.338578)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-49"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g id="matplotlib.axis_2">
    <g id="ytick_1">
     <g id="line2d_7">
      <defs>
       <path d="M 0 0 
L -3.5 0 
" id="mb3962c627d" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;"/>
      </defs>
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="57.6" xlink:href="#mb3962c627d" y="307.584"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_7">
      <!-- $0.0$ -->
      <g transform="translate(37.877811 310.961289)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="ytick_2">
     <g id="line2d_8">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="57.6" xlink:href="#mb3962c627d" y="254.3616"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_8">
      <!-- $0.2$ -->
      <g transform="translate(37.877811 257.738889)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-50"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="ytick_3">
     <g id="line2d_9">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="57.6" xlink:href="#mb3962c627d" y="201.1392"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_9">
      <!-- $0.4$ -->
      <g transform="translate(37.877811 204.516489)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-52"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="ytick_4">
     <g id="line2d_10">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="57.6" xlink:href="#mb3962c627d" y="147.9168"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_10">
      <!-- $0.6$ -->
      <g transform="translate(37.877811 151.294089)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-54"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="ytick_5">
     <g id="line2d_11">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="57.6" xlink:href="#mb3962c627d" y="94.6944"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_11">
      <!-- $0.8$ -->
      <g transform="translate(37.877811 98.071689)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-56"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g id="ytick_6">
     <g id="line2d_12">
      <g>
       <use style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.8;" x="57.6" xlink:href="#mb3962c627d" y="41.472"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g id="text_12">
      <!-- $1.0$ -->
      <g transform="translate(37.877811 44.849289)scale(0.1 -0.1)">
       <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-49"/>
       <use transform="translate(49.8132 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#CMMI10-58"/>
       <use transform="translate(77.408707 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-48"/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g id="patch_3">
    <path d="M 57.6 307.584 
L 57.6 41.472 
" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-width:0.8;"/>
   </g>
   <g id="patch_4">
    <path d="M 414.72 307.584 
L 414.72 41.472 
" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-width:0.8;"/>
   </g>
   <g id="patch_5">
    <path d="M 57.6 307.584 
L 414.72 307.584 
" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-width:0.8;"/>
   </g>
   <g id="patch_6">
    <path d="M 57.6 41.472 
L 414.72 41.472 
" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-width:0.8;"/>
   </g>
   <g id="text_13">
    <!-- Example flow -->
    <defs>
     <path d="M 59.703125 16.84375 
L 56.90625 16.84375 
C 51.90625 6.078125 47.59375 3.703125 33.296875 3.703125 
L 30.59375 3.703125 
C 25.703125 3.703125 21.5 4.203125 20.796875 4.921875 
C 20.296875 5.21875 20.09375 6.3125 20.09375 8.03125 
L 20.09375 32.90625 
L 35.5 32.90625 
C 43.703125 32.90625 45.203125 31.5625 46.5 23 
L 48.796875 23 
L 48.796875 46.203125 
L 46.5 46.203125 
C 45.796875 42.234375 45.40625 40.78125 44.296875 39.421875 
C 43 37.765625 40.203125 37 35.5 37 
L 20.09375 37 
L 20.09375 58.84375 
C 20.09375 61.609375 20.703125 62.203125 23.40625 62.203125 
L 36.90625 62.203125 
C 48.203125 62.203125 50.40625 60.71875 52.09375 51.78125 
L 54.59375 51.78125 
L 54.296875 66 
L 1.203125 66 
L 1.203125 64.09375 
C 8.59375 63.5 9.90625 62.09375 9.90625 55.078125 
L 9.90625 10.609375 
C 9.90625 3.59375 8.5 2.09375 1.203125 2.09375 
L 1.203125 0 
L 55.203125 0 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-69"/>
     <path d="M 27.796875 0 
L 47.90625 0 
L 47.90625 1.5 
C 44.796875 1.5 42.796875 3.09375 39.703125 7.5 
L 26.90625 27.109375 
L 35.203125 39.09375 
C 37.09375 41.796875 40.09375 43.40625 43.296875 43.40625 
L 43.296875 45 
L 27.5 45 
L 27.5 43.40625 
C 30.5 43.40625 31.5 42.8125 31.5 41.390625 
C 31.5 40.171875 30.296875 37.96875 27.796875 34.828125 
C 27.296875 34.234375 26.09375 32.421875 24.796875 30.40625 
L 23.40625 32.40625 
C 20.59375 36.59375 18.796875 40 18.796875 41.296875 
C 18.796875 42.703125 20.09375 43.40625 23.09375 43.40625 
L 23.09375 45 
L 2.40625 45 
L 2.40625 43.40625 
L 3.296875 43.40625 
C 6.296875 43.40625 7.90625 42.109375 11 37.4375 
L 20.40625 23.109375 
L 9 6.59375 
C 6 2.5 5 1.796875 1.703125 1.5 
L 1.703125 0 
L 16.203125 0 
L 16.203125 1.5 
C 13.40625 1.5 12.203125 2 12.203125 3.296875 
C 12.203125 3.90625 12.90625 5.40625 14.203125 7.40625 
L 22.09375 19.703125 
L 31.203125 5.703125 
C 31.59375 5.09375 31.796875 4.5 31.796875 3.90625 
C 31.796875 1.921875 31.09375 1.5 27.796875 1.5 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-120"/>
     <path d="M 44.203125 6.609375 
C 42.5 5.203125 41.296875 4.703125 39.796875 4.703125 
C 37.5 4.703125 36.796875 6.09375 36.796875 10.5 
L 36.796875 30 
C 36.796875 35.203125 36.296875 38.09375 34.796875 40.5 
C 32.59375 44.09375 28.296875 46 22.40625 46 
C 13 46 5.59375 41.09375 5.59375 34.796875 
C 5.59375 32.5 7.59375 30.5 9.90625 30.5 
C 12.296875 30.5 14.40625 32.5 14.40625 34.703125 
C 14.40625 35.09375 14.296875 35.59375 14.203125 36.296875 
C 14 37.203125 13.90625 38 13.90625 38.703125 
C 13.90625 41.40625 17.09375 43.59375 21.09375 43.59375 
C 26 43.59375 28.703125 40.703125 28.703125 35.296875 
L 28.703125 29.203125 
C 13.296875 23 11.59375 22.203125 7.296875 18.40625 
C 5.09375 16.40625 3.703125 13 3.703125 9.703125 
C 3.703125 3.40625 8.09375 -1 14.203125 -1 
C 18.59375 -1 22.703125 1.09375 28.796875 6.296875 
C 29.296875 1.09375 31.09375 -1 35.203125 -1 
C 38.59375 -1 40.703125 0.203125 44.203125 4 
z
M 28.703125 12.234375 
C 28.703125 9.125 28.203125 8.21875 26.09375 7.015625 
C 23.703125 5.609375 20.90625 4.703125 18.796875 4.703125 
C 15.296875 4.703125 12.5 8.125 12.5 12.4375 
L 12.5 12.84375 
C 12.5 18.765625 16.59375 22.390625 28.703125 26.796875 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-97"/>
     <path d="M 1.90625 39.796875 
C 3.203125 40.09375 4 40.203125 5.09375 40.203125 
C 7.703125 40.203125 8.59375 38.59375 8.59375 33.78125 
L 8.59375 8.421875 
C 8.59375 3 7.203125 1.5 1.59375 1.5 
L 1.59375 0 
L 23.796875 0 
L 23.796875 1.5 
C 18.5 1.5 17 2.59375 17 6.53125 
L 17 34.90625 
C 17 35.09375 17.796875 36.09375 18.5 36.796875 
C 21 39.09375 25.296875 40.796875 28.796875 40.796875 
C 33.203125 40.796875 35.40625 37.265625 35.40625 30.1875 
L 35.40625 8.25 
C 35.40625 2.609375 34.296875 1.5 28.59375 1.5 
L 28.59375 0 
L 51 0 
L 51 1.5 
C 45.296875 1.5 43.796875 3.203125 43.796875 9.421875 
L 43.796875 34.703125 
C 46.796875 39 50.09375 40.796875 54.703125 40.796875 
C 60.40625 40.796875 62.203125 38.09375 62.203125 29.796875 
L 62.203125 8.703125 
C 62.203125 3 61.40625 2.203125 55.59375 1.5 
L 55.59375 0 
L 77.5 0 
L 77.5 1.5 
L 74.90625 1.796875 
C 71.90625 1.796875 70.59375 3.59375 70.59375 7.5 
L 70.59375 28.15625 
C 70.59375 39.984375 66.703125 46 59 46 
C 53.203125 46 48.09375 43.40625 42.703125 37.609375 
C 40.90625 43.296875 37.5 46 32.09375 46 
C 27.703125 46 24.90625 44.59375 16.59375 38.296875 
L 16.59375 45.796875 
L 15.90625 46 
C 10.796875 44.09375 7.40625 43 1.90625 41.5 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-109"/>
     <path d="M 0.90625 39.3125 
C 1.796875 39.40625 2.5 39.40625 3.40625 39.40625 
C 6.796875 39.40625 7.5 38.40625 7.5 33.671875 
L 7.5 -13.359375 
C 7.5 -18.578125 6.40625 -19.703125 0.5 -20.296875 
L 0.5 -22 
L 24.703125 -22 
L 24.703125 -20.203125 
C 17.203125 -20.203125 15.90625 -19.09375 15.90625 -12.75 
L 15.90625 3.109375 
C 19.40625 -0.203125 21.796875 -1.203125 26 -1.203125 
C 37.796875 -1.203125 47 10.046875 47 24.609375 
C 47 37.0625 40 46 30.296875 46 
C 24.703125 46 20.296875 43.5 15.90625 38.09375 
L 15.90625 45.796875 
L 15.296875 46 
C 9.90625 43.90625 6.40625 42.59375 0.90625 40.90625 
z
M 15.90625 33.375 
C 15.90625 36.390625 21.5 40 26.09375 40 
C 33.5 40 38.40625 32.359375 38.40625 20.6875 
C 38.40625 9.546875 33.5 2 26.296875 2 
C 21.59375 2 15.90625 5.609375 15.90625 8.625 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-112"/>
     <path d="M 1.90625 62.5 
L 2.5 62.5 
C 3.59375 62.5 4.796875 62.5 5.59375 62.5 
C 8.796875 62.5 9.796875 61.09375 9.796875 56.40625 
L 9.796875 8.703125 
C 9.796875 3.296875 8.40625 2 2.09375 1.5 
L 2.09375 0 
L 25.703125 0 
L 25.703125 1.703125 
C 19.40625 1.703125 18.203125 2.703125 18.203125 8.25 
L 18.203125 68.296875 
L 17.796875 68.5 
C 12.59375 66.796875 8.796875 65.796875 1.90625 64.109375 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-108"/>
     <path d="M 40.796875 16.453125 
C 36 8.8125 31.703125 5.90625 25.296875 5.90625 
C 19.59375 5.90625 15.296875 8.8125 12.40625 14.53125 
C 10.59375 18.34375 9.90625 21.65625 9.703125 27.796875 
L 40.5 27.796875 
C 39.703125 34.265625 38.703125 37.140625 36.203125 40.328125 
C 33.203125 43.921875 28.59375 46 23.40625 46 
C 18.40625 46 13.703125 44.203125 9.90625 40.796875 
C 5.203125 36.703125 2.5 29.59375 2.5 21.40625 
C 2.5 7.59375 9.703125 -1 21.203125 -1 
C 30.703125 -1 38.203125 4.921875 42.40625 15.75 
z
M 9.90625 31 
C 11 38.734375 14.40625 42.40625 20.5 42.40625 
C 26.59375 42.40625 29 39.609375 30.296875 31 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-101"/>
     <path id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-3"/>
     <path d="M 25 46 
C 12 46 2.90625 36.40625 2.90625 22.59375 
C 2.90625 9.09375 12.203125 -1 24.796875 -1 
C 37.40625 -1 47 9.59375 47 23.40625 
C 47 36.5 37.796875 46 25 46 
z
M 23.703125 43.203125 
C 32.09375 43.203125 38 33.59375 38 19.90625 
C 38 8.59375 33.5 1.796875 26 1.796875 
C 22.09375 1.796875 18.40625 4.203125 16.296875 8.203125 
C 13.5 13.40625 11.90625 20.40625 11.90625 27.5 
C 11.90625 37 16.59375 43.203125 23.703125 43.203125 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-111"/>
     <path d="M 57.09375 45.5 
L 57.09375 44 
C 60.5 43.296875 61.5 42.59375 61.5 40.90625 
C 61.5 39.390625 60.90625 36.984375 59.796875 34.28125 
L 50.796875 12.03125 
L 42.40625 34.484375 
C 40.703125 39.078125 40.703125 39.078125 40.703125 40.40625 
C 40.703125 42.59375 41.796875 43.296875 46.5 44 
L 46.5 45.5 
L 26.203125 45.5 
L 26.203125 44 
C 29.90625 43.59375 31.09375 42.5 33.09375 37.078125 
C 33.796875 35.1875 34.5 33.265625 35.09375 31.46875 
L 26 11.53125 
L 16.09375 37.6875 
C 15.703125 38.6875 15.5 39.6875 15.5 40.703125 
C 15.5 42.796875 16.703125 43.59375 20.09375 44 
L 20.09375 45.5 
L 2.09375 45.5 
L 2.09375 44 
C 4.40625 43.796875 5.203125 42.796875 7.40625 37.6875 
L 20.90625 3.421875 
C 22.09375 0.40625 22.90625 -1 23.5 -1 
C 24 -1 24.796875 0.3125 26 2.90625 
L 37.203125 26.953125 
L 46.296875 3.3125 
C 47.703125 -0.390625 48.09375 -1 48.703125 -1 
C 49.40625 -1 49.90625 -0.09375 51.5 3.921875 
L 65.296875 38.578125 
C 67.09375 42.796875 67.40625 43.296875 69.40625 44 
L 69.40625 45.5 
z
" id="Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-119"/>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(202.936854 35.472)scale(0.12 -0.12)">
     <use transform="scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-69"/>
     <use transform="translate(60.871631 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-120"/>
     <use transform="translate(110.684831 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-97"/>
     <use transform="translate(154.9184 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-109"/>
     <use transform="translate(232.42677 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-112"/>
     <use transform="translate(282.23997 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-108"/>
     <use transform="translate(309.93514 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-101"/>
     <use transform="translate(379.075309 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-3"/>
     <use transform="translate(434.466986 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-111"/>
     <use transform="translate(481.789557 0)scale(0.996264)" xlink:href="#Nimbus_Roman_No9_L_Regular-119"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597231/matplotlib-does-not-display-latex-fonts-correctly).

Comment: This [seems to be a known bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8068).

Comment: I am curious what the content of the SVG looks like. Can you include it in your question please?

Comment: I have found a work-around, which is satisfying for me: use \kern0pt e.g. plt.title("Example with f\kern0pt low"). Then the characters f and l are exported to the svg file, however, still all characters are converted to curves.